# How to compare Firebase data with Login authentication screen input. Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am making Login functionality and I need to compare the data I stored in Firebase with the input I am giving in the Login screen, so the user could login if he is registered in the system, right now it's working just for the first particular child from "Customer" but I need it to work with all so when I will add other users it could recognize them too. It should be compared with these 3 fields from database (email, password, active).

[The database] https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUUFK.jpg

````
public class LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    EditText email;
    EditText password;
    String username, pass, isActivate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

        email = findViewById(R.id.email_signin);
        password = findViewById(R.id.passwordSignin);

        mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customer").child("1");
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                username = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                pass = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();
                isActivate = dataSnapshot.child("active").getValue().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void backClick(View view) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public void signIn(View view) {
        if(allowedToSignin()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomerScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"Login failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

    public boolean allowedToSignin(){
        boolean signinAllowed = true;

        if(email.getText().toString().equals(username) && isActivate.equals("true")){
            email.setError(null);
        }else {
            email.setError("enter a valid email");
            signinAllowed = false;
        }
        if (password.getText().toString().equals(pass)){
            password.setError(null);
        }else {
            password.setError("enter a valid password");
            signinAllowed = false;
        }
        return signinAllowed;

    }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvOla.png
````

Comment: Update. I solved the problem by adding Query and making a new method

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the other way around.

1. Let the user sign in with Firebase Auth signin method.

2. Get their userid with `userId = mAuth.getCurrentUserId()`

3. Use this userId in your database to check if user is "active" if not signout the user automatically and throw an error on UI.

This means in your database userdata will be at `mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customer").child(userId);`